# Increase clickable area of an SVG border

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have SVG shapes made from edges using stroke and no fill.

Is there a way to increase the clickable area of an SVG border?

If it were just a shape I could just add a border with stroke width to make the clickable area larger. However, I am already using the borders.

Adding a second and larger layer underneath (second "path" in the same "g" but transparent) will not work either as there is a selection mechanism in place that would break if we clicked on the second layer instead of the visible layer, as well as the fact that the elements are being redrawn (they are links between boxes in a graph and they update as I move the boxes around in real time), and the code that does that is sealed in an API.
However, if the two layers could work as if there was only one in a way, that would work.

EDIT: Here's a sample of one of the shapes.

```
<g>
    <path class="graph_edge" d="M239.25 -185.8L290.125 
        -185.8L290.125 -281L341 -281">
    </path>
</g>
```

As it stands, I would rather not add an id if possible nor can i change anything about the existing path.

Comment: I think you've added sufficient constraints that no solution is possible.

Comment: @RobertLongson I was starting to think that myself. An exception might be made for the if I just explore the DOM on load and add them.

Comment: The normal solution to this type of request is to add a second copy of the paths that is transparent and has a thicker stroke. Such as in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559876/svg-hover-state-on-multiple-layers-not-only-top-layer/52571096#52571096).  But whether you can arrange this with your constraints is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you use no fill, only the stroke is clickable. You may use a transparent fill to make the shape clickable inside. However: if you want only the stroke to be clickable you can reuse your shape with `<use>` with a wider transparent stroke, put them both in a group and make the group clickable

```css
#clickable:hover{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="150" viewBox="0 0 250 150">
 <defs> 
  <rect id="therect" x="20" y="20" height="80" width="100" >
  </rect>
  </defs>
  
<g  id="clickable">

<use xlink:href="#therect" stroke="#006600" stroke-width="5" fill="none" fill-opacity="0.5" />

<use xlink:href="#therect" stroke="#000" stroke-width="25" fill="none"  stroke-opacity="0" />

</g>
</svg>
```

UPDATE the OP comments that "each edge is made using a "path", has no id and doesn't use references." In this case:

1. I create the array of all paths with the class `.graph_edge`
2. I close the all these paths (the path the OP gave me) with javascript by adding a z to the end of the d attribute.
3. In CSS I add a transparent border to the shape. This is increasing the clickable area of the shape but won't be visible.

**PS** Very strange edge shape!

```js
let pathsArray = Array.from(
document.querySelectorAll(".graph_edge"))


pathsArray.forEach(p =>{  
  let thisD = p.getAttributeNS(null,"d");
  p.setAttributeNS(null, "d", thisD+"z")
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}

.graph_edge{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,0); stroke-width:15px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "230 -290 120 120"><g>
    <path id="test" class="graph_edge" d="M239.25 -185.8L290.125 
        -185.8L290.125 -281L341 -281">
    </path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution if i had control over the content or structure of the SVG. As it stands, each edge is made using a "path", has no id and doesn't use references. See the sample I edited in my question. Also, the path is the clickable element, not the "g".

Comment: I might be a bit confused but it seems in your update, you have just hidden the border of the shape (stroke (0,0,0,0)) and made it large. That does not work because the stroke has to show, it simply must be clickable from farther away (as if the border itself had a second invisible larger border). Think of it as an invisible css shadow-box that's clickable (around the border/edge).

Comment: so you need a border for a border? I don't understand you. can you share a real example?

Comment: Something like that yes, I want to be able to click on that border as if it were larger than it is. For example in https://jsfiddle.net/6mqkuo1a/, i would like the grey area to stay transparent, but be clickable and behave as if it were the black edge, not the second path. Keep in mind that the edges move in real time with a drag of boxes that those edges link.